# xmpp delete account from server

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xmpp

I'm writing an app that use `XmppFramework` for Ios and `Xmpphp` for the server side. What i wanna do is delete my user account in the openfire server by `xmppFramework` or by `Xmpphp`. 
Maybe i have to use Xep-1033 as administrator?

```
<iq from='bard@shakespeare.lit/globe'
id='delete-user-1'
to='shakespeare.lit'
type='set'
xml:lang='en'>
<command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' 
       action='execute'
       node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#delete-user'/>
</iq>
```

If yes how i can traslate this in a method for xmppFramework or Xmpphp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a solution using xmppFramework or Xmpphp, so i have installed an openfire plugin. With this plugin i can manage,add or delete the users in my server trought http request.

Comment: Could you share how to use this plugin?